# download file using angular2 and spring

Tags: java, spring, angular2-routing

I am trying to download file using spring code and my code are running but there is no file downloaded in download folder. here my code are:-

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/downloadRecordFile/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public void downloadRecordFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


     File fileName = new  File("C:\workarea\UplodedRecords\test_annotation.pdf");
     if (fileName != null) {         
                if (!fileName.exists()) {
                String errorMessage = "Sorry. The file you are looking for does not exist";
                log.info(errorMessage);
                OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(errorMessage.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                outputStream.close();
                return;
            }

            String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName.getName());
            if (mimeType == null) {                    
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }

            log.info("mimetype : " + mimeType);
            response.setContentType(mimeType);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; filename=\"" + fileName.getName() + "\""));
            response.setContentLength((int) fileName.length());
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

            //Copy bytes from source to destination(outputstream in this example), closes both streams.
            FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
            inputStream.close();
            response.getOutputStream().flush();

        }
    }
}
```

My code is not givivng error or exception but it was not downloading file.

angular 2 code:-

```
function downloadRecord() {
        alert("Downloading");
        var record_id = 1234;
        downloadRecordFile.query({id: record_id}, onSuccess);
    }
```

here is my service js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('testApp')
    .factory('downloadRecordFile', downloadRecordFile);

 downloadRecordFile.$inject = ['$resource'];

function downloadRecordFile($resource) {
    var resourceUrl = 'api/downloadRecordFile/:id';
  return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
              'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
              'get': {
                  method: 'GET',
                  transformResponse: function (data) {
                      if (data) {
                          data = angular.fromJson(data);
                      }
                      return data;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  })();
```

Is there any error in code please help me.

Comment: Why do you use `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` if it's downloading? Try to remove.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Then provide more info. Do you see logs? the controller is invoked? How to you call the downloading? What is sent from browser and what you get in the controller? Whether the file exists or not? Statement "not working" means nothing. It's your code and we cannot guess what's wrong without seeing the info.

Comment: I am using angular2 to calling get method:-

Comment: don't place it in comments. update the question

Comment: I have update question..